# cannot access WSDL for my java webservice

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jboss, wsdl

I hava been developing a webservice in Java SE 6 with the Webserver JBOSS 5 and have been trying to work around a problem that came up when I attempted to access my web service's wsdl file through a jsp page I created.  I got this error :

```
13:32:13,324 WARN  [ServiceDelegateImpl] Cannot access wsdlURL:http://127.0.0.1:8080/RepEngSDK/?wsdl
```

at first i researched why I would get this error and how to get around it and that led me to a thread on this website on how to setup certificates and keyStores and trustStores

[Problem calling web service from within JBOSS EJB Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814016/problem-calling-web-service-from-within-jboss-ejb-service)

which then pointed me to this thread:

[Java client certificates over HTTPS/SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl)

So I started setting my certificates and keystores and when it came to set Java's system properties such as javax.net.ssl.keyStore with the cmd line

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=...
```

I get a no classdeffound error for javax.net.ssl.keyStore, javax.net.ssl.trustStore etc...

Looking back at my error message and the threads I was using to get around it I noticed I wasn't even attempting at first to connect through a https url like these people had been trying to connect with.

SSL authentication is not necessary for my webservice but I can't seem to figure out why I get ServiceDelegateImpl error in the first place.  I am completely at a loss on what to do from here.

Admittedly this is my first attempt at a webservice and I am worried that I am completely looking over simple problems.  I apologize in advance if this is the case but I promise have been researching very diligently and attempting any solutions I have come across.

Comment: is RepEngSDK the name of your webservice? or the Application?

Comment: The problem could be with the URL you are using. RepEngSDK?wsdl instead of RepEngSDK/?wsdl ; The URL should follow the path http://<ip>:<port>/<app name>/<webservice name>?wsdl

Comment: I just knew it had to be something so obvious that I was overlooking.  the problem was as you mentioned @Sean,  the correct URL to access was http://localhost:8080/RepEngSDK/BOEReportEngineSDK?wsdl.  And that works fine.  Thanks alot for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since your using **http://** not **https://** you don't need to worry about setting a keystore up with certs. That can save yourself a headache right there.

2) I think the problem is the url you are using. RepEngSDK/?wsdl, It doesn't look right, would guess at...

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/RepEngSDK/repengsdk?wsdl
```

or just...

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/RepEngSDK?wsdl
```