# spring controller accept only local requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is there any easy way in Spring Security to lock down an `@Controller` to only accept requests from the same (local) host?

I was looking at this post:
[Securing servlet URL without using username password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862325/securing-servlet-url-without-using-username-password-authentication)

However, I was wondering if that is actual best practice vs. some  other security measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`hasIpAddress`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) expression in the filter security interceptor.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/32')"/>
    ...
</http>
```