# Spring security :Accept request from specific domain only

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In spring security application how can I identify that request is coming from some specific domain only?

In my spring controller there are handler that insert data to DB , I want that this handler should be called from particular domain `xyz.com` only if a request comes from `abc.com` it should be denied.

I check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796399/spring-controller-accept-only-local-requests) and when i do this firefox show `The page isn't redirecting properly`
is that a correct behaviour? or is there any other way to denied other domain request?

My app is running on `http://localhost:8084/`.

If I pass `access="hasIpAddress('127.0.0.2/8085')` it shows

```
09:30:11,426 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:165 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

If I pass `access="hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/8085')` it throws

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.IpAddressMatcher.matches(IpAddressMatcher.java:75)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.IpAddressMatcher.matches(IpAddressMatcher.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot.hasIpAddress(WebSecurityExpressionRoot.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: paste here your beans.xml

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you have to use the hasIpAddress correctly. Note, what comes after the '/' is not the port, but the subnet. The second exception you got (IndexOutOfBounds) is due to the fact you should not pass 4 items...

read here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/95303-how-to-use-hasipaddress

Comment: can't we pass port number with ip address

Comment: unfortunately not. but why do you need to pass the port number, anyway? don't you care about the host name only?

Comment: i think you are right.checking host name only will be more than enough to avoid cross domain request.right?