# How to call web service with unknown certificate

Tags: web-services, ssl, https, wsdl2java

I have generated client stub using wsdl2java.
I am able to call webservices of HTTP server. 
But I have HTTPS server with self signed certificate.
When I called same service for HTTPS server, its throwing exception :
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

How to modify client stub to accept all certificates?

Answer (score 0):

You have one of two options:

1. Trust the cert. One possible approach is this: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/
2. Alternatively, choose to ignore the error and keep going. See this stackoverflow q: [How to ignore PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626965/how-to-ignore-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertp)

Google is your friend...