# JIRA Rest API change issue status --> 401 error

Tags: api, rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I'm trying to change the status of a Jira Issue with the Rest API, as described here: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.3-m01-1/

I post to the URL

```
XXXXXX/rest/api/latest/issue/Project-Key/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```

However, it doesn't work :(, I get a an 401 error (unauthorized), even though i authenticate like described in the atlassian documentation. (user used to authenticate has the permission to change the status)

```
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("username", "password"));
WebResource webResource = client.resource(getDestination());
```

Though, get request works fine an returns:

```
 {
    "expand": "transitions",
    "transitions": [{
        "id": "961",
        "name": "Deploybar",
        "to": {
            "self": "https://issues.xxxxxxxxx.local/jira/rest/api/2/status/10009",
            "description": "",
            "iconUrl": "https://issues.xxxxxxxxx.local/jira/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
            "name": "Deploybar",
            "id": "10009",
            "statusCategory": {
                "self": "https://issues.xxxxxxxxx.local/jira/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
                "id": 4,
                "key": "indeterminate",
                "colorName": "yellow",
                "name": "In Arbeit"
            }
        },
        "fields": {
            "assignee": {
                "required": false,
                "schema": {
                    "type": "user",
                    "system": "assignee"
                },
                "name": "Bearbeiter",
                "autoCompleteUrl": "https://issues.xxxxxxxxx.local/jira/rest/api/latest/user/assignable/search?issueKey=RCE-98&username=",
                "operations": ["set"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to post:

```
final WebResource webResTransition = jiraTransition.response();
final ClientResponse crTest = webResTransition.accept("application/json").type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, {"transition": {"id": "961"}});
```

**My try with Jira Rest Client:**

```
final JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
    final URI jiraServerUri = new URI("https://issues.teamspace.local/rest/api/latest");
    final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "username", "password");
    final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
    final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("Issue-Key", pm);
```

**Error Message:**

```
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:75)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.getAndParse(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:80)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.getIssue(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:113)
    at at.racon_linz.jenkins.stash_plugin.test.JiraTest.testClient(JiraTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.executeMethod(DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.java:213)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClientHandler.handle(ApacheHttpClientHandler.java:175)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:191)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$1.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:84)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:54)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:135)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1565)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.executeMethod(DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.java:210)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1188)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
    ... 51 more
```

**Error without HTTPS**

```
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 302
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:70)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.getAndParse(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:80)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.getIssue(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:113)
at at.racon_linz.jenkins.stash_plugin.test.JiraTest.testClient(JiraTest.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 302
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:676)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:191)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$1.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:84)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:54)
    ... 22 more

I tried everything I found about this topic, but nothing was working :(

Comment: What version of Jira REST Java Client are you using?

Comment: Check this https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Home, probably you are using an old version.

Comment: I edited my question with my try with Jira Rest Client

Comment: Look at this entry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626965/how-to-ignore-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertp/13627599#13627599

Comment: Where do i Install the all-trusting trust manager in JerseyClient? The Example only shows a HttpsUrlConnection, sry I'm new in connecting to rest api's :(

Answer (score 1):

First thing you might want to do is export the JIRA certificate and try to add it to your local Java JRE/JDK installation directory using KeyTool import command :

- keytool -importcert -file "C:\Users***\Desktop\JIRA.crt" -keystore
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts" 
  -storepass ***** -alias Jira

Once you are done with that, try to run your client service and see if the issue goes away.

If not then worst case scenario is that, you can by pass the client service cert validation by passing TrustManager object within sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom()). Please see below for more detail implementation.

```
private TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chck = null;
            return chck;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }
    } };


sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance().trustStoreFile(trustStoreFile).trustStorePassword(trustStorePassword);
        // sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ;

        basicAuth = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(username, userPassword);
        clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJsonProvider().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        clientConfig.getSingletons().add(jacksonJsonProvider);
        client = Client.create(clientConfig);
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, userPassword));
        webResource = client.resource(uri);
```