# "PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" Only in release version

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ssl-certificate, shiro, java-security

The issue is something tricky. I tried to connect my war file to a Active Directory via LDAPS. While running with Debug Mode from IntelliJ IDEA, the code is working perfectly fine.

When I Install the war files in same or different machine, am facing this error.

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The certificates are self-signed. I have added the CA.crt in `truststore.jks`, LDAP.cer in `cacerts`. I also tried adding in the `jssecacerts', but same result.

Note: Am using Apache Shiro framework.

How to avoid this error? Why it is not coming in the debug mode?

Comment: Where are you "deploying" it to? The same machine?

Comment: Apparently you couldn't import the corresponding correct certificate into your truststore...

Comment: Yes and No, Tried in the same machine and other machine @rmlan

Comment: @SercanOzdemir I have added the certificate to truststore.jks file also.

Comment: Did you also add the corresponding properties to your run-configuration of the server where you deploy your war? Something like `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path/to/your/truststore>` in the start options?

Comment: It worked @Frank! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a Shiro problem.  It is a problem with your certificates.  I suspect your IDE may be using a different Java install than where your deployed WAR is executing from.

This exception has been handled previously [How to ignore PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626965/how-to-ignore-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertp).

Also, I found this article useful [PKIX path building failed: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely its **problem with certificates**. Thing that worked for me was, placing required certificate in ***C -> program files-> java -> jre -> lib -> security*** location. After pasting cerificate at this loaction, **build successful**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VPN or a forward proxy, you just need to add the certificate of your proxy to Java cacerts.

check this answer on how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619478/4144572