# Sent Email alert from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, email, smtp

I need to send email alert from my MATLAB program. I used below code to do that. But it is giving an error. How can I fix it?

```
function recipient = matlabmail(recipient, message, subject, sender, psswd)

if nargin<4
    sender = 'mysender@gmail.com';
    psswd = 'password';
end

setpref('Internet','E_mail',sender);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.gmail.com');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username',sender);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password',psswd);

props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class', ...
                  'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','465');

sendmail('receive@gmail.com', 'Send Mail from Matlab', 'Hi from MATLAB');
```

This is the error massage I got:

> > email
> >     Error using sendmail (line 171)
> >     Exception reading response;
> >     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> >     sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Error in email (line 42)
sendmail('receive@gmail.com', 'Send Mail from Matlab', 'Hi from MATLAB');

Answer (score 1):

As the error says: It does not find any certificate (that the connection is trusted).

Check this question, I am sure that one of the solutions will be sufficient for you (ignoring or adding a certificate):

[How to ignore PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626965/how-to-ignore-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertp)

Comment: How can I do it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

I was success when I allow less secure app access to my account. Go to the "Less secure apps" section in My Account. Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. 
Also I have to turn off my Antivirus software.