# jaspersoft studio 6.2 XML Data source ssl error

Tags: ssl, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio, xmldatasource

I am trying to add an "XML File" datasource in Jaspersoft Studio 6.2 to a report which is actually a call to a REST service requiring a single parameter as part of the path.

[image: Data Adapter Wizard]

if the image doesn't display here is a description:

The URL I use is like so : `http://.../service/rest/report/`

Options:

GET

Parameter:

name=id

value=$P{ReportID} (the parameter is already created with a default value)

When I try to test it, this is what happens

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.http.HttpDataConnection.getInputStream(HttpDataConnection.java:101)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.DataFileStream.<init>(DataFileStream.java:47)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.DataFileUtils.getDataStream(DataFileUtils.java:62)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.xml.XmlDataAdapterService.loadDataDocument(XmlDataAdapterService.java:140)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.xml.XmlDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(XmlDataAdapterService.java:70)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:105)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:162)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:59)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know this should work.  I can call the service in a browser using `.../report/?id=xx` and I get back the expected XML data.  I have also tested this using the "WebService Data Source" plug-in found on the community.jaspersoft.com site - that works as well in the Studio app (but I am unable to configure it on the server).

So the question is, how do I get around this SSL exception? My app server is internal and does not use SSL (still under development).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a two ways to tackle this:

- Ignore the certificate all together (Be aware that ignoring the error makes you **vulnerable to MITM** attacks)
- Add the certificate to your keystore *of the corresponding JVM*

For more details take a look here: [How to ignore PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626965/how-to-ignore-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertp)

Comment: so basically, if the server is on an internal network and NOT accessible from the outside, I would not actually worry about a certificate and would instead try to just ignore the build error?  I can try that...