# Google Cloud Speech SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, x509, google-speech-api

I have developed an application using Google Cloud Speech to translate audio into text.

I have had some issued with certificate for ssl:
- At first I was adding to jks the certificate for https://*.googleapis.com, but this certificate was changing every week. 
- Then I added the certificate for GEOTrust, which was the certifier for google apis. This has been working ok until one month ago aprox.
- Now I am trying to modify my application to trust any certificate using XTrustProvider (https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/ssl-trust-provider-for-java).

I already know how to install certificates into the keystore, maybe I do not know which certificate to install.

I would rather implement a Provider that trusts all certificates, but installing a certificate that does not expire (any time soon) could be also a solution.

Here is the trace of the exception I am getting:

```
    11/04/2018 18:03:33:866 ERROR - RPC failed: {0}
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:230)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:211)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:144)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechGrpc$SpeechBlockingStub.recognize(SpeechGrpc.java:241)
    at plusnet.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:84)
    at plusnet.RecognizerFacade.recognize(RecognizerFacade.java:50)
    at flow.subflow.MatriculaGoogle.getTextGoogle.servletImplementation(getTextGoogle.java:61)
    at com.avaya.sce.runtime.BasicServlet.handleRequest(BasicServlet.java:112)
    at com.avaya.sce.runtime.AppServlet.processRequest(AppServlet.java:96)
    at com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.requestHandler(SCEServlet.java:243)
    at com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.doGet(SCEServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:319)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:149)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:135)
    at io.grpc.auth.ClientAuthInterceptor.getRequestMetadata(ClientAuthInterceptor.java:150)
    at io.grpc.auth.ClientAuthInterceptor.access$100(ClientAuthInterceptor.java:64)
    at io.grpc.auth.ClientAuthInterceptor$1.checkedStart(ClientAuthInterceptor.java:96)
    at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$CheckedForwardingClientCall.start(ClientInterceptors.java:195)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.startCall(ClientCalls.java:273)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncUnaryRequestCall(ClientCalls.java:252)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.futureUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:189)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:135)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:317)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 63 more
```

I would like this XTrustProvider or any other alternative to work. Or, if I have done something wrong adding the certificates to the jks and I can correct this, that would be fine also.

Thank you very much in advance.

Ricardo.

Comment: Trust any certificate is a very insecure solution. You may check if the certificate is still valid (not expired or revoked). Maybe try lates JRE version which should contain an updated certificate store.

Comment: Hello Konrad, thanks for your reply. I know that trusting any certificate is not the best solution. I have found how to do this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24501156/7936103). I would like to add the proper certificate, but I don't know which one is it. As I said, googleapis.com certificate is changing every week and the application is already in production.