# HttpClient https Post request fails

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I'm trying to issue a **post** request in the next manner:

- I use Apache's [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) **3.1**
- I use encoding "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
- The URL I use starts with https

this is the code I try to run:

```
public static String httpsPost(String url, String body, String mediaType, String encoding) {
   disableCertificateValidation();
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(body, mediaType, encoding);
   PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
   method.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
   client.executeMethod(method);
}

public static void disableCertificateValidation() {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
            }};

    // Ignore differences between given hostname and certificate hostname
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Upon executing `executeMethod` I catch:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried to [disable certificate validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047996/ignore-self-signed-ssl-cert-using-jersey-client) but it did not help.

Comment: please post your complete code of your HTTP client setup including the SSLContext initialization and setting. Also, which version of HttpClient are you using? 3? 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored my old code to handle **https**. Now it works and looks like this:

```
public static String httpsPost(String url, String body, String mediaType, String encoding) {
    SSLContext ctx;
    ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[]{new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
    SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());

    URL serverUrl = new URL(url);

    HttpsURLConnection con =  (HttpsURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.connect();

    OutputStreamWriter post = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    post.write(body);
    post.flush();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    String content = "";
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content += inputLine;
    }
    post.close();
    in.close();

    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ignore the certificate all together then take a look at the answer here [Ignore self-signed ssl cert using Jersey Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047996/ignore-self-signed-ssl-cert-using-jersey-client)

Although this will make your app vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

You can instead of this try adding the certificate to your java store as a trusted cert. This site may be helpful. http://blog.icodejava.com/tag/get-public-key-of-ssl-certificate-in-java/

Here's another answer showing how to add a cert to your store. [Java SSL connect, add server cert to keystore programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755180/java-ssl-connect-add-server-cert-to-keystore-programatically)

The key is

```
KeyStore.Entry newEntry = new KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(someCert);
ks.setEntry("someAlias", newEntry, null);`
```

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, I tried to Ignore. It did not work.

Comment: Then try adding the certificate to your java store as a trusted cert

Comment: The thing is, when I issue the request using Postman, it succeeds without adding any certificate or anything else. I do not see why in my code it does not

Comment: yes, it does. I will check again my certificate loading

Comment: Yes, it pushed me to the right direction. Thank very much :)

Comment: @Igor : Mark the answer as a solution then for future people with the same problem please