# Ignore self-signed ssl cert on CentOS using ftp4j on client

Tags: java, apache, ssl, ftp, ftp4j

Task: Connect to a CentOS box using FTP4J FTP using a self signed certificate.

I am able to successfully connect to the CentOS box over FTP using

`org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient`

however I receive the following error, which I know to be from the self signed certificate, using FTP4J.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047996/ignore-self-signed-ssl-cert-using-jersey-client) here on SO asked a similar question, just with a Jersey Client. The answer there (cleaned up below, as the accepted answer yields a compiler error) does not work.

Here is the FTP4J code with the trust all certs code, which does not work.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferListener;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPIllegalReplyException;

FTPClient ftpsClient = new FTPClient();
try
{
    // Initialize the transfer information.
    this.oFtpArgs.oFtp.transferCount = this.oFtpArgs.pathFiles.size();
    this.oFtpArgs.oFtp.transferCompleted = 0;
    this.oFtpArgs.oFtp.filePercentComplete = 0L;
    this.oFtpArgs.oFtp.bytesTransferredTotal = 0L;

    // Connect to the server using active mode enabling FTP over explicit TLS/SSL (FTPES).
    ftpsClient.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES);
    ftpsClient.setPassive(false);
    ftpsClient.connect(this.oFtpArgs.serverIp, port);

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager()
    {
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){return null;}
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
    }};

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Log into the server.
    ftpsClient.login(user, pass);
}

catch (IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The Apache FTPSClient code connects flawlessly, just has trouble doing uploads, hence the FTP4J code now.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClientConfig;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;

FTPSClient ftpsClient = new FTPSClient("TLS", false);
try
{
    FTPClientConfig ftpClientConfig = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX);
    ftpsClient.configure(ftpClientConfig);
    ftpsClient.connect(this.oFtpArgs.serverIp, port);
    int ftpReplyCode = ftpsClient.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpReplyCode))
        return;

    // Set protection buffer size
    ftpsClient.execPBSZ(0);

    // Set data channel protection to private
    ftpsClient.execPROT("P");

    // Log into the server.
    ftpsClient.login(user, pass);
    ftpReplyCode = ftpsClient.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpReplyCode))
        return;

    // Enter local active mode .
    ftpsClient.enterLocalActiveMode();
}

catch (IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I did peruse other questions, but could not find something that worked. Any thoughts on how to tell FTP4J to ignore errors on self-signed certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close. First of all, get rid of the reference to `HttpsURLConnection`. Has absolutely nothing to do with FTP or FTPS.

But keep the `TrustManager` and `SSLContext` stuff, with just one minor change.... direct your `FTPClient` to use the resultant `SSLSocketFactory`.

So your final result looks something like this:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager()
{
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){return null;}
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
}};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
ftpsClient.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

My source? [The FTP4J manual](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php#6). (I do note that that example there uses "SSL" instead of "TLS"; you may have to try it both ways.)

Comment: You were not kidding in that I was close. Thank you. I was missing one line, `ftpsClient.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());`, and had an extraneous line.