# how to consume restful service over https with certificate using jersey client

Tags: java, rest, jersey

We are securing or application - currently we have a REST Service which we are calling from our REST program which is using jersy api like below

```
Client client = Client.create(config);
client.setFollowRedirects(true);
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://myserver/myws");
resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
String result = resource.post(String.class);
```

but now we have https service like this

"https://myserver/myws"

and the other application interface has shared with us the SSL Certificates.

What changes i now need to do in the code to make this communication secure using jersy api ?

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate in the server?

Comment: yeah its a self-signed certificate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6047996/2587435

Comment: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/How-to-setup-Https-connection-with-self-signed-certificate-td7579659.html

Comment: http://adambien.blog/roller/abien/entry/jax_rs_client_javax_net

Comment: Just google it for more options.

Comment: @Paul - our certificate is not self signed. My apologies.