# How can I read a https request with Clojure?

Tags: https, clojure

Clojure seems to support HTTP with clojure.contrib.http.agent, but how can I read from HTTPS?

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/HTTPS#Clojure - does that help?

Comment: I "get javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target  " when I try that

Comment: You need to put the appropriate code certificate in the Java keystore.  See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=407886 for some things to point in the right direction.

Comment: @Jeff How about adding that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Clojure, after all, is hosted on the Java platform. Hopefully, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl) can set you on the right path.