# Certificate java client https

Tags: java, ssl, https, client, keytool

I have to create a client in java that makes a https connection to a server. I have my certificate that i use with my browser to log into the web site. How can i use the same certificate on my java client?
Should i add it to the Keystore?

Thank you

New information:
Server and Client are both in the same host -> localhost
The Client has to make a request to https:// localhost:8183
I create the user's certificate typing:

```
$ ./build-key fg1
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out fg1.pfx -inkey fg1.key -in fg1.crt -certfile ca.crt -name default
```

then i did

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore fg1.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore VEPClientRestKeyStore.jks  -srcalias default -destalias fg1 -destkeypass <mypassword>
```

Now i'm really lost.HOw can i use this keystore to connect to server and make requests?
Thank you again.

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl

Comment: @tigran Why? There's nothing there about how to get a client certificate out of a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently wrote a [blog post](http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2013/01/https-with-client-certificates-on.html), complete with examples, for doing this on Android, though the code for making the connection is the same on the desktop.

You basically have two choices - either import the certificate into a java Keystore using keytool as indicated by the post pointed to by tigran, or create the keystore in memory as needed, as in the example that accompanies my blog post.