# windows azure java client calling RESTFUL API

Tags: java, windows, azure, restful-authentication

Can we connect to windows-azure mobile service from a java client as mentioned in the below url ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj710106.aspx

because when i connected it is giving me 403 error. I was able to connect with application key but not with the auth header.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

OF course you can.
403 ERROR is Authentication Error.
Do you add the client Certificate to the header?
You need upload a Certificate to Windows Azure.
Then use add this certificate to your https request.

For how to upload certificate please refer to :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg551722.aspx 
How to add client cer to http reqeust header:
[Java client certificates over HTTPS/SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl)

Comment: Did n't work.. still i am getting the same issue now response code has changed to 401.

Comment: 401 is unauthorized. Did you trust the cert?