# Get whole html code - Java?

Tags: java, html, url

I wanted to write a code that prints out the whole html code from a website, so I could get information about a certain player. My Problem now is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class DownloadPage {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    URL url = new URL("http://apps.runescape.com/runemetrics/app/levels/player/Gragoyle");

    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is =con.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line = null;

    // read each line and write to System.out
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
}
```

When i run this code it only prints the overview:

```
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Id be very grateful if you could explain me how I can print the whole html code, and what I did wrong.

Comment: Often servers check headers to know if the client is a bot or if it's a browser, that's likely why you are having this issue. Anyway, if you look at the source code of the provided link (Ctrl+U on Chrome), you'll find that the body is actually quite empty, the page gets filled by some script. Scripts run client-side, so just using an HTTPConnection like you do will not make you able to read useful data from that page.

Comment: For me the body isnt empty at all, I can see all the information I need. How else could I get this information?

Comment: The body is not empty if you look at the webpage. I said, look at the source code: http://i.stack.imgur.com/z2JAk.png The body is empty, at first it seems a AngularJS app, so javascript fills the page when it's loaded.

Comment: When I look at the elements from the website directly i get all the information I need: http://i.imgur.com/w6hQX5V.png How can i access this?

Comment: That's because "elements" is not the page source. The Elements tab shows a tree containing what is currently displayed, so everything added by javascript is listed there. As I said, javascript is executed client side, so chrome executes it and lets you see the generated elements from the "Elements" tab. This is not gonna happen with java, it won't execute javascript unless you emulate a browser, so you'll get the **source code (CTRL + U to see it)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

1. What you get from `http://apps.runescape.com/runemetrics/app/levels/player/Gragoyle` is a redirection to `https://apps.runescape.com/runemetrics/app/levels/player/Gragoyle`. This redirection is used to force users to connect by HTTPS.
2. If you try to get data from `https://apps.runescape.com/runemetrics/app/levels/player/Gragoyle` you will get an SSL exeception. You can see more about it on: [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl). If you resolve this (fe. by accepting all certificates, not recommended in production) you will get HTML file, but it wouldn't be useful, because there is no player data on it.
3. The data you actually want to get is retrieved by Javascript and AJAX calls. This is a great information for you, because you if you resolve problems with SSL you can get player data as JSON file, by calling fe.

`https://apps.runescape.com/runemetrics/profile/profile?user=Gragoyle&activities=20`

Then you can use any JSON parser fe. [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to easily get values you want.

Note: To view JSON file in nice and readable form you can use [this site](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) or some plugin for your browser like [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) for Chrome.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the clear answer. Just one more question, how did you find out the data was stored in https://apps.runescape.com/runemetrics/profile/profile?user=Gragoyle&activities=20 ?

Comment: I opened Development Tools and there is a Network tab where you can see requests. I use Chrome. https://i.gyazo.com/318995fec81b836b125d1cdc2d0c1a7b.png