# Establishing connection to HTTPS using client certificates

Tags: java, ssl, https, client-certificates

I want to upload a file to a HTTPS-server using Java.
The server is not a open URL hence I need a client certificates to establish a connection.
I am having `.pem , .jks , .pkcs12` client certificate files.

Can any one suggest me how to use this certificate files in my application to establish communication ?
Do I need to use all 3 certificate files ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java client certificates over HTTPS/SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.jks` file is the Java Keystore. It should contain the correct client certificates (and maybe also the intermediate certificates from the certificate chain).

I assume you are going to write a client that uploads the file to the HTTPS server? Then you should use the `.jks` file with the client certificate with the (let's say apache) `HttpClient`.

You need to create a `SSLContext` and load the keystore

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new File("keystore", "yourPassword".toCharArray(), new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
```

Then you have to put the `sslContext`in a `SSLConnectionSocketFactory`

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
```

And then finally build the `HttpClient`

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

After all these steps the httpClient should use your client certificate from the keystore for your desired request.