# How to make rest client call over https?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

How to do the resttemplate configuration to make call over https and the response will be a 302 redirect.

Trying to make rest tamplate call to a server over https with a Bearer token after authentication of the token the server do a 302 redirect.

```
String redirectUrl="https://example.com/redirect";
String authHeader="Bearer eyJhbGciO";
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        requestHeaders.set("Authorization", authHeader);
        Map<String, Object> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, requestHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<ModelAndView> modelres = restTemplate.exchange(redirectUrl,HttpMethod.GET,requestEntity, ModelAndView.class,uriVariables);
```

How to make rest client call over https?

Comment: and what issues are you seeing?

Comment: What is your question? We dont solve your daily tasks from school.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the SSL certificate to make an https call.
Get the certificate and configure.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl) may help you